# Considering inflation, what's the value of Euro today (January, 2011) compared to 2005?

Tags: inflation, eur-euro, european-union

So what would be 1000 Euro from 2005 worth today (January, 2011), considering the inflation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The European Central Bank's Harmonised Index of Consumer Prices was set at 100 in 2005. In December 2010, the most recent month for which it's available, it was 111.3. So €1000 in 2005 would buy you the same amount of stuff as €1113 would now.

Source: http://sdw.ecb.europa.eu/reports.do?node=100000181